# can jquery read the dom elements of external pages?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to read and parse the dom elements of third party websites like cnn.com (for e.g) so that I can get the div, a, p tags and read the position and size information?

jquery can parse and show information of the web page where your javascript code is running but if we provide an external web page to the .load command, can we parse the third party website page and read the DOM tree?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you will be blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which restricts one site from accessing another on a different domain.  You could set up a server-side script, in your preferred language, which would fetch the website on behalf of your JavaScript code, but this is more complex than just using AJAX to request the page.

Comment: Can you do it with a bookmarklet? I saw some bookmarklets that overlay on top of the current page. If that is the case then the bookmarklet code should be able to read the current page's DOM tree, right?

Comment: @Nilesh: a bookmarklet can read the top-level page's DOM tree, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot access other domains' content with javascript due to security reasons. At least in secure browsers...